# bugzilla shared between different sites with inequal network access

Tags: bugzilla

I am trying to find a good solution to have a single instance of Bugzilla accessed by different groups and some of those groups may have very slow or even intermittent network access.

As far as I can tell, trying to run several instances of bugzilla and keep a database in sync is not really a good idea. Mirroring / sync can be part of the solution, even if there are risks or accessing old data sometimes...

Just wondering if anybody had run into similar problem before and/or if there is some good (or creative) way to go about it.

(And no, there is nothing I can do about the network access speed or reliability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing which comes to mind is [Deskzilla](http://almworks.com/deskzilla/), which has offline support.

Comment: Apparently Mylyn has this support also. I did not think about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bugzilla Addons](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons) page on the Mozilla wiki lists a load of desktop and mobile clients, some of which may have offline support. If these are using the Bugzilla APIs, they will also use less bandwidth than web-based interactions.

If you still wanted to have people access Bugzilla over the web, then you could reduce bandwidth use by using the latest version, which has paged search results (so someone doesn't download a buglist of 20,000 bugs).